# Sending scheduled emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a bit complicated problem and I need help more exprienced Developers. I have application to create contracts. When contract is created it is sended to customer by sideiq with attachment of contract in pdf format.

In Contract model I have two fields

- repeat_type which is string and have the following options("monthly", "weekly", daily)
- repeat_every which is an integer.

So for example I create a contract that repeat_typ is "monthly" and repeat_every value is 2. So this contract should be repeated every two months. So it should send mail for example today and 2 months later. I don't know how to solve this problem. I was trying to use Sidekiq and Sidetiq with "recurrence" but this option is not to much configurable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a gem to help you with this. Check this out:

Revised railcast 
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

I'd recommend that you use the "Whenever" gem:

https://github.com/javan/whenever

With this gem you can write something like this:

```
every :saturday, at: "4:38am" do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. But every contract can have different dates which should be send. One Contract will be sended twice a month but next one twice a year. How can I do this with whenever gem?

Comment: You can run the same job every day (or even every hour if you like). The job then decides by a query on a date column, say `next_delivery_at <= NOW()`, when the next email is delivered. Upon successful delivery, the job increments `next_delivery_at` by the value specified in `repeat_every` and `repeat_type`. You can still keep Sidekiq to get the retry functionality.